# react hooks invalid hook call with context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm trying to write a simple component that, upon rendering fetches the gameState from an API and conditionally renders the appropriate component. I am using Context to store the state, but I keep getting an invalid hook call when I call the dispatch.[enter image description here][1]

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Landing from './Components/Landing/Landing';
import {PokerContext} from './DrawPokerContext';


const initialState = {
  token : null,
  pokerGame : false,
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATEGAME":
      localStorage.setItem("pokerGame", JSON.stringify(action.payload.pokerGame));
      localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(action.payload.token));
      return {
        token: action.payload.token,
        pokerGame: action.payload.pokerGame
      };

    case "SETGAME":
      localStorage.setItem("pokerGame", JSON.stringify(action.payload));
      return {
        pokerGame: action.payload,
        token: null
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};


function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <PokerContext.Provider value = {{state, dispatch}}> 
    <div>
    <Landing /> 
    </div>
    </PokerContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {PokerContext} from '../../DrawPokerContext';
import PlayerLanding from './PlayerLanding';
import AdminLanding from './AdminLanding';
import axios from 'axios';



const Landing = () => {
const {state, dispatch} = React.useContext(PokerContext);
const [isFetched, setFetched] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchGame();
}, []);

async function fetchGame() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/game/board').then(res => {
    return res.data.game;   
}).then(game => {
    dispatch({
        type: "SETGAME",
        payload: game,
    });
    return game;
}).then(() => {
   setFetched(true);
});
};

// if no game was found
if (state.pokerGame === false ) {
    return "Loading";
}    

// if there is no admin in the game
else {
    if (!state.pokerGame.adminName) {
        return <AdminLanding />;
    }
    return <PlayerLanding />;
   }
}
export default Landing;
```

```js
import React from 'react';

export const PokerContext = React.createContext();
```

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
```

This is the error that I am getting that I am not able to resolve. I checked there is only one version of React, and the react/react-dom are of the same version so I am not really sure how to resolve the error that is being shown below. I am very new to React and would appreciate any insight into this. Thank you.

Error Message:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

```js
  18 |     axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/game/board').then(res => {
  19 |     return res.data.game;   
  20 | }).then(game => {
> 21 |     dispatch({
  22 |         type: "SETGAME",
  23 |         payload: game,
  24 |     });
```

Comment: You need to define AND call your `fetchGame` function inside the useEffect call.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not change the error being outputted.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-curie-7scv1?file=/src/Landing.js. Seems to work for me. Can you create a reproducible demo

Comment: That was helpful, thank you. It ended up being an issue of having multiple versions of React, not the code itself.